# how to control interface orientation in splitview

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my splitview application i present a login dialog when no shared secret is stored inside the application settings. This requires the application to stop rotation for the time this dialog is presented. I achieved this by overriding the detailview controllers shouldAutorotate method to something like this:

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
   return ![SynchronizationHandler displaysLoginWindow];
}
```

However with the recent release of iOS 6.0.1 this method never gets called. I already did some search but i did not find any information regarding this specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 6.0.1 seems to use the shouldAutorotate method only for the rootviewcontroller of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Use `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {}` instead